# Fixed effect and random intercept models using "lavaan" in R: advice on coding

Tags: r, r-lavaan, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-model

I´m trying to fit some **path models** (i.e. all variables are observed; no latent variables) using “**lavaan**” in **R**. I´ve been able to do this successfully for a model where the data are **completely pooled (Model 1, below)**. But, the data are grouped and I´d like to fit a models that account for groups as **fixed effects (Model 2, below)** and **random effect (i.e. random intercept by group; Model 3, below)**.

I´ve looked at the user manual and various other online resources, but **I´m having trouble working out how to code the fixed and random effects models.**

I´m hoping someone might be able to provide some advice on this.

I´ve include *simplified versions* of the data and models I´m trying to fit below. (I´m using a path model as the real data includes more predictors and indirect paths).

**Dataset**: the variables are 4 predictors (P1-4); 1 outcome (Outcome); 4 groups (each observation falls within one of four groups: G1-4 are dummy variables). All variables are observed (i.e. no latent variables).

**Model 1**: path model without accounting for groups (i.e. **complete pooling**)
This appears to work fine.

model1 <- "
#regression equations
P2 ~ P1
outcome ~ P1 + P2 + P3 + P4
# variance of exogenous vars
P1 ~~ P1
P3 ~~ P3
P4 ~~ P4
# covariance of exogenous vars
P3 ~~ P4
# residual var for endog
P2 ~~ P2
outcome ~~ outcome
# covar of endog vars (none)
"
fit1 <- lavaan(model1, data=mydata)

**Model 2: group fixed effects**
I´m not sure how to do this…
**Question:** Is this done by including all but one of the group dummy variables as exogenous variables, specifying paths from each dummy variable to the outcome, as well as including a variance term for each dummy? That is:

Model2 <- "
#regression equations
P2 ~ P1
outcome ~ P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + **G2 + G3 + G4**
#variance of exogenous vars
P1 ~~ P1
P3 ~~ P3
P4 ~~ P4
**G2 ~~ G2**
**G3 ~~ G3**
**G4 ~~ G4**
# covariance of exogenous vars
P3 ~~ P4
# residual var for endog
P2 ~~ P2
outcome ~~ outcome
# covar of endog vars (none)
"
fit2 <- lavaan(model2, data=mydata)

**Model 3: random intercept for groups**
I see you need to specify the level 1 (observation level) and level 2 (group level) equations. I´m not sure how to do it correctly, but my attempt is below.
**Question:** What is the correct way to specify a model that has random intercepts for groups? And, when fitting the model, how do I specify cluster correctly?

Model3 <- "
#regression equations
**level 1:**
P2 ~ P1
outcome ~ P1 + P2 + P3 + P4
**level 2:**
outcome ~ **G2 + G3 + G4**
# variance of exogenous vars
P1 ~~ P1
P3 ~~ P3
P4 ~~ P4
**G2 ~~ G2**
**G3 ~~ G3**
**G4 ~~ G4**
# covariance of exogenous vars
P3 ~~ P4
# residual var for endog
P2 ~~ P2
outcome ~~ outcome
# covar of endog vars (none)
"
fit3 <- lavaan(model3, data=mydata, **cluster =”????”**)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Simon

Answer (score 1):

Means and (co)variances of exogenous predictors are by default (`fixed.x=TRUE`) taken as given, so there is no need to estimate them (i.e., you can leave them out of your model syntax).

In Model 3, leave the G dummy codes out of the model.  Use the name of the original grouping variable (with 4 levels) as the `cluster=` argument, which will invoke random intercepts for all modeled variables. Or, if you only specify a single-level model, the `cluster=` arguments triggers cluster-robust *SE*s and test statistics.  That might be better than random intercepts because you only have $N=4$ at Level 2.  ML-SEM gives highly biased estimates in small samples.  But perhaps that is what your comparison of approaches is meant to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer Terrence. Very much appreciated.